# Data comparison in java

Tags: java

There are around 1,700,000 rows of data in a table1 and 900,000 rows of data in table2 and these tables are stored in different databases.
I am trying to compare each of them to know if data in table1 exists in table2 or not, by
getting data into 2 Resultsets and comparing them roughly like this:

```
while(Resulset1.next())
 {
   while(Resultset2.next())
    {
      if(Resultset1.getString("whatever").equalsIgnoreCase(Resulset1.getString("whatever")))
       {
       ........
       }
    }
 }
```

When using `ResultSet` it is so slow.
How can I compare them faster? Any recommendation?

Comment: Why not do this with SQL?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? Maybe a more complex `SQL` query should help you

Comment: Could you at least fix the code?

Comment: Looks like you re reading one table from database for each row of another. It is slow. Try to cache query result first.

Comment: @JamesAnderson because tables are stored in different databases

Answer (score 1):

Retrieving common whatever using SQL:

```
SELECT whatever FROM TableA WHERE whatever IN (SELECT whatever IN TableB)
```

If you must do it in Java I suggest populating two HashSets and

```
setRepresentingTableA.retainAll(setRepresentingTableB)
```

setRepresentingTableA will contain common whatevers.

Comment: Upvoted that if you must do this Java side then the OP needs to use a hash-table method (e.g. `HashSet` as proposed).

Comment: The OP has commented that the two tables are in different data bases so SQL it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

One way of comparing across databases in an environment that doesn't support heterogeneous queries is to compare in batches.

Suppose we start with a query

```
SELECT whatever FROM <Table-1>;
```

Where `Table-1` is one of the tables to compare.

The first comparing query is:

```
SELECT <field-list> FROM <Table-2> WHERE whatever IN ( V1 , V2 , ... , V1000);
```

Where the 1000 values V1 thru V1000 are taken from Table-1.

The next query is:

```
SELECT <field-list> FROM <Table-2> WHERE whatever IN ( V1001 , V1002 , ... , V2000);
```

How well this performs depends on factors like whether there is a suitable index including `whatever` on table-2. My expectation is that all things being equal it's faster to 'look' for the smaller table in the larger table just because it will require fewer batches.

Obviously there is nothing special about chunks of 1000 and you might want to work out what the practical limit is for the length of SQL string the server will accept!
If you could cram 10000 values you'd be done on 90 queries!

One further uplift might then be to use a prepared statement rather than executing SQL strings.
Remember to handle odd-end chunks by then running a special query or back-filling the slack variables.

**PS:** One very significant benefit of this line of attack is that it doesn't place unbounded memory demands on the Application Server (wherever the Java is running).
The other methods such as hash-tables are valid but the storage demands they place on the App. Server grow as the database tables grow.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate answer to this is do not bring  all the data into Java and compare. Just bring the data matches to your criteria.

Pass both values to a query and write a query in sql.

Comment: tables are in different databases (different connections), so I cant match them with Sql, I need to compare all of them in Java

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `1,700,000 * 900,000` queries to the data base. Try downloading sets of rows from the tables and iterating over them. I suggest an example in **pseudocode**:

```
set1 = getNext5000RowsFromTable1
set2 = getNext5000RowsFromTable2

while (set1.isNotEmpty() && set2.isNotEmpty()) {
    foreach (row1 : set1){
        foreach (row2 : set2) {
            if (row1.getString("field").equals(row2.getString("field")){
                .....
            }
        }
    set1 = getNext5000RowsFromTable1
    set2 = getNext5000RowsFromTable2
}
```